# How to block users from getting messages?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I am beginner in rails. I am building a forum application. It has a messaging facility where users can privately message(not real time. it is like a notification.) to other users. I already achived this. But I want to add blocking feature where user can block other users to avoid getting messages from those particular users. How can i do this? I appreciate your answers. Thanks in advance.
Here is my code.
**Notifications Controller**

```
 class NotificationsController < ApplicationController

    layout "posts"

    after_action :read_message, only: [:index]

    def index
        @notifications = Notification.where(:recipient_id => session[:registered_id]).order("created_at DESC")

    end

    def new
        @user = User.find(session[:user_id])
        @notification = @user.notifications.new
    end

    def create
        @user = User.find(session[:user_id])
        @notification = @user.notifications.new notification_params
        if @notification.save
            redirect_to(:controller => "posts", :action => "index")
        else
            render "new"
        end
    end

    def sent_messages
        @notifications = Notification.where(:user_id => session[:user_id]).order("created_at DESC")
    end

    private

    def notification_params
        params.require(:notification).permit(:message, :user_id, :recipient_id, :status)
    end

    def read_message
        @notifications = Notification.where(:recipient_id => session[:registered_id]).order("created_at DESC")
        @notifications.read_all
    end
 end
```

**Notification model**

```
class Notification < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :user

    validates :message, :presence => true
    validates :recipient_id, :presence => true

    def self.read_all
       Notification.all.update_all(status: true)
    end    
end
```

**Notification migration**

```
class CreateNotifications < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :notifications do |t|
      t.text :message
      t.integer :user_id
      t.string :recipient_id
      t.boolean :read, default: false

      t.references :user, index: true, foreign_key: true

      t.timestamps null: false
    end
  end
end
```

** Notifications#index**

```
<div id = "messages_wrapper">

<% @notifications.each do |notification| %>


    <div class="<%= notification.status ? 'message_wrapper_read' : 'message_wrapper_unread' %>">
        <p><%= notification.message %></p>
        <% if notification.user_id %>
            <p class = "message_details">from <span><%= notification.user.registered_id %></span></p>
        <% end %>       
    </div>

<% end %>

</div>
```

Comment: You're asking us to design and implement a feature for you, which is outside the scope of Stack Overflow. You need to try to code the feature yourself and then ask when you have a specific problem that you can't solve on your own. I can tell you that you need a table mapping blockers to blockees (both foreign keys to user_id), and the rest should be relatively easy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the blocked users concept, you can add a custom attribute in user model called as `blocked_users` which is stored as an array in the db.

For postgresql you can use array datatypes.

In you `notification.rb` file,

```
#Validations,
validate :is_not_blocked_by_recipient

def is_not_blocked_by_recipient
  #Check if the user is blocked or no, and write the logic
  #self.errors.add()
end
```

It should work

Comment: I will try this. Thank u